# Is it better to design in 16 bit mode in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, rgb

What is the ideal color mode to design in photoshop cross platform/ multi device product design? Default seems to be 8 bit mode, however 16 bit mode seems to hold more color information. What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Design for what? Anything more than 8 bit is generally for photo editing, not design, since screens and presses can't render more than 8 bits.

Comment: @Scott: He probably refers to banding effects that might appear from applying/stacking many effects layers while searching for best design (e.g. Gamma 0.18 > Brightness 100, Contrast 97). Even when resulting image will be 8-bit, when exporting it from 16-bit mode more details are preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Ya editing in 16 bit is much better than 8 bit mode
but the problem is when working with 16-bit images, the file size is much larger than you’d have with an 8-bit image.

[check here for the benefits of working with 16-Bit images in photoshop](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/16-bit/)